# Two different applications hosted on JBoss Portal Server are having combined logging

Tags: logging, jboss, log4j

On JBoss Portal Server 2.7.2, we have two different wars having log4j.xml seperately in them are having combined logger entries. We are using commons-logging over log4j.

App1 configured File1.log as their logger output file in their log4j.xml, App1.war hosted on JBoss Portal.

App2 configured File2.log as their logger output file in their log4j.xml, App2.war hosted on JBoss Portal.

Current Scenario --> App1 logger entries are coming in File1.log
                     App2 logger entries are coming in File2.log

Required Scenario --> Only App1 logger entries should be written in File1.log
                      Only App2 logger entries should be written in File2.log
                      and Server log is a different file.

What is that we are missing here, and how to rectify the problem.

Thanks & Regards
JavaDeveloperIndiaHyd.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your app based log files at runtime by using `RoutingAppender`, then in that case the app specific logs won't messed up with server logs.

To create a runtime `RoutingAppender` you can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17846463/591061)