# Accessing MDC key value inside File element of log4j2.xml

Tags: logging, log4j, slf4j, multi-tenant, mdc

I am trying to do something like the following in the `log4j.xml`:

```xml
<File name="MyFile" fileName="logs/%X{client}]">
    <PatternLayout>
        <Pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
    </PatternLayout>
</File>
```

I have set the key as follows from the java code:

```c
MDC.put( "client", "Roger" );
```

I have tried `${client}` as well inside the `log4j2.xml`
nothing works. How do I refer the MDC key inside the `log4j2.xml` outside the layout element?

I have also specified a default value for the key under the properties section as follows:

```xml
<Properties>
    <Property name="client">default</Property>
</Properties>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the `%X` pattern converter (which is only for layouts), you want to use a [lookup](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/lookups.html).

In this case, there is a built-in lookup that does what you want: the [Context Map Lookup](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/lookups.html#ContextMapLookup).

Example usage:

```xml
<File name="MyFile" fileName="logs/$${ctx:client}]">
```

Comment: $${ctx:client} does not work. It creates the file as ${ctx

Comment: Are you sure that there is a value for that key in the thread context for every thread that does logging?

Comment: yes it does, but i also tried the default value as in the specified in the question section

Comment: You may have found a bug. Would you mind creating a bug report on the Log4j2 JIRA issue tracker?

Comment: By the way, your question mentions `MDC.put(...`, but the Log4j2 API class is `ThreadContext`. Have you tried using `ThreadContext.put("client", "Roger")` instead?

Comment: will try that @Remko Popma

Comment: log4j2 provides a implementation of slf4j's `MDCAdapter`, which is a wrapper for `ThreadContext` operations. In other words, using `MDC.put(` via slf4j or `ThreadContext.put` via the log4j2 API has the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Routing RoutingAppender` to wrap file appender, and in `Routing RoutingAppender` can use `MDC` to separate file.

Find example here:
[write different logs in different files with log4j2 (MDC)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17827923/how-to-write-different-logs-in-different-files-with-log4j2-mdc-in-xml)

Reference:
[RoutingAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#RoutingAppender)